# storing data from checkboxes to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

```
<script>
  function checkValue(){
     var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

     if ( $('#student').val() == ""  ) {
        alert('Please select any student!');
        return false;
     }
     else {
        if(checkboxes.is(":checked")) {
           return true;
        }
     }
```

I have my checkboxes working just fine; I need to know how to proceed with it so that it stores the values of checkboxes to DB.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you want to store in the DB exactly? How is your table structured? You want to store #student value?

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the following:

```
<%= form_for :model %>
  <% f.check_box :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<%= form_for :model %>
  <% check_box_tag :model_field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `simple_form` for your needs.  It's very popular and built on top of formtastic.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/ for details.

You can also see great implementation detail at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form